# Open VPN Configurations

Tags: linux, bash, vpn, openvpn

I would like to configure OpenVPN to automatically login using my credentials (similar to how you can configure ssh to automatically login using a specific key). Also, it would be nice to have a single macro that all of my .ovpn files (which are in a the same directory).

I've searched this stack exchange site, and I found some similar questions, but none of them seemed to get a satisfactory answer. I also found [this](https://support.invizbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007887233-Configure-OpenVPN-using-your-VPN-credentials-on-Linux) blog post, but it requires you to download some Gnome gui software.

When I tried to tackle this on my own, I ran

```
ls | grep -v .ovpn
```

To find the files in the directory that are not .ovpn, and I get four options in stdout.

```
client/
configurations
server/
update-resolv-conf
```

Where configurations is a zip archive and update-resolv-conf is a bash executable. The other two are empty directories. Again, it would be ideal to configure this for all my ovpn files in a single place.

Edit: I'm trying to connect a host to a VPN for privacy. More specifically, I have a Raspberry Pi that I'm trying to use as an SSH and VNC host for a small set of specific users, who are on different LAN.

Comment: so what kind of tunnel do you want? are you connecting a pair of networks, or connecting a client to a VPN privacy proxy, or are you trying to allow clients to connect to your LAN? describe the device you want to set this up on, including the OS. it sounds like a headless or cli-only server; is it? do you control both ends of the connection? what kind of clients are in play?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my post.